# Issue while adding Parameters to an Oracle Stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

So there's an existing report that I am revamping. We need to maintain the old one as well. So I created a stored procedure and I believe that the SP works fine. I tested it in PL/SQL. Following is the code for executing the existing SP

```
    public static DataSet getReportDataAssetQualityCrisil(string pSPName, int v_UID, string v_FromDt, string v_ToDt, int v_round, string Flag,
                string v_Gilt, string RequestSessionID, string ReportName)
            {
                string strErrMsg = "";
                try
                {
                    DataSet objInvDataSet = null;
                    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MutualFund");
                    objInvDataSet = new DataSet();
                    DbCommand dbCmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(pSPName);
                    dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    db.DiscoverParameters(dbCmd);

                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "v_UID", v_UID);
                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "v_FromDt", v_FromDt);
                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "v_ToDt", v_ToDt);
                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "v_round", v_round);
                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "v_Flag", Flag.ToUpper().ToString());

                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "v_Gilt", v_Gilt);
                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "V_REQUESTSESSIONID", RequestSessionID);
                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "v_REPORTTYPE", ReportName);
                    db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "resultset_out", null);
                    objInvDataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCmd);

                    return objInvDataSet;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    strErrMsg = ex.Source;
                    strErrMsg = ex.Message;
                    strErrMsg = ex.StackTrace;
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

> ```
> The new report has fewer parameters. Following is the code for the new procedure that I created.
> ```

```
        public static DataSet getReportDataAssetQualityCrisilRevised(string pSPName, string V_FROMDT, string V_TODT, int V_UID, string RequestSessionID)
        {
            string strErrMsg = "";
            try
            {
                DataSet objInvDataSet = null;
                Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MutualFund");
                objInvDataSet = new DataSet();

                DbCommand dbCmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(pSPName);
                dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                db.DiscoverParameters(dbCmd);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "V_FROMDT", V_FROMDT);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "V_TODT", V_TODT);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "V_UID", V_UID);                
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "RESULTSET_OUT", null);
                db.SetParameterValue(dbCmd, "V_REQUESTSESSIONID", RequestSessionID);

                objInvDataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCmd);

                return objInvDataSet;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strErrMsg = ex.Source;
                strErrMsg = ex.Message;
                strErrMsg = ex.StackTrace;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

However, when the control of execution goes over db.setParameterValue, I get an exception which says "An OracleParameter with ParameterName 'V_FROMDT' is not contained by this OracleParameterCollection."

Both the functions are in the same class.

Comment: Does `SetParameterValue` also add the parameter to the command, or does it just set the value like the name implies? Also, are parameter names case sensitive?

Comment: Honestly, I am not aware of it. I have found one thing though. If I change the name of my procedure to the one which already exists above, the system is able to pick the parameters, which kind of tells me that there is some kind of mapping somewhere. I searched the name of the existing SP in my entire solution and I couldn't find it anywhere else,

Comment: @Crowcoder, Now that I've used oracle for a while, the oracle parameter names aren't case sensitive in C#.

Comment: @Crowcoder Also, the discover parameter method actually connects to the SP in the database to get the number of parameters. There was a compile-time error in my Oracle SP, which is why I was getting this issue. Since I have an MS SQL background, I never knew that oracle saved SPs with compilation errors, because MS SQL doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compilation error in the Stored procedure was responsible for this error.